# If $P(a)=0 \Rightarrow P(a+1)=1$ then $P(x)$ has no repeated roots.

Tags: polynomials

> Let $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be polynomial with all real roots and has the property that $P(a)=0 \Rightarrow P(a+1)=1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $P(x)$ has a repeated root.

I think this problem statement is not true because if we suppose that $P(x)=x$ then $P(0)=0 \Rightarrow P(1)=1$, $\;P(x)$ has no repeated root.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us suppose that $P \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ has degree $k$, i.e., it has complex roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ with
$$
P(x)=c\prod_i(x-\alpha_i)
$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are distinct complex and $c\neq 0$. In addition, we know that
$$
P(x)-1=c\prod_i(x-\alpha_i-1).
$$
In particular, the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ of $P(x)$ verifies
$$
-c\sum_i \alpha_i = - c\sum_i (\alpha_i+1).
$$
This is impossible whenever $k\ge 2$.

---

Edit: The condition of $\alpha_i$ being distinct is necessary. Indeed, the polynomial $P(x):=x^k$ has all roots real and equal to $0$, and $P(a)=0 \implies P(a+1)=1$ for all $a \in \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: The last equality is just a particular instance $[x^i]P(x)=[x^i](P(x)+Q(x))$ which holds whenever $i>\mathrm{deg}(Q(x))$.

Comment: Why is there no contradiction if a repeated root exists?

Comment: There is still a contradiction if a repeated root exists. But a false statement implies anything. So we can still claim a repeated root exists. https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&ei=31uIWZ3aHpHQwAK0n62ICQ&q=false+statement+implies+anything&oq=false+statement+implies&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.0.0i22i30k1.7905.55358.0.55933.31.26.3.1.1.0.193.3860.0j25.25.0....0...1.1j4.64.mobile-gws-hp..2.29.3934.3..0j5j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i19k1.yYdvHlDwYwk

Comment: @user236182 $x^2$ is the counterexample

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti you have misunderstood a little. First of all the roots are real. The problem doesn't say that if a polynomial has multiple roots $\zeta$ then $P(\zeta+1)=1$ but the reverse. If it has roots such that $P(\zeta+1)=1$ then $\zeta$ is a multiple root

Comment: @Raffaele I just considered the more general question where $P(x)$ has complex coefficient and complex distinct roots; and, for each complex root $\alpha$, then $\alpha+1$ is a root of $P(x)-1$. Btw, your answer above appears to me quite nonsense.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Nonsense because it works? Take $P(x)=(x-1)^3$ and compute $P(2)$

Comment: @Raffaele  ..indeed $1$ is a multiple root of $P$ and you confirming the result just for that choice of $P$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti No no no. I have proved what I am saying. I'll add to my answer

Comment: I get the idea from Paolo Leonetti's general solution and I do my work for real number. Thank you very much for all your help, Paolo Leonetti, Lord Shark the Unknown and Raffalel.:)

Comment: @Raffaele Please check the comment at your answer

Comment: @carat You're welcome

Answer (score 4):

You need the degree of $P$ to be $d\ge2$. If so then
$$P(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\ldots(x-a_d)$$
for **distinct** $a_i$. Then
$$P(x)-1=(x-a_1-1)(x-a_2-1)\ldots(x-a_d-1).$$
Can you get a contradiction from these?

Answer (score 0):

For $n>1$ we have $P(x)=(x-a)^n$ then $P(a+1)=(a+1-a)^n=1$

If $P(x)$ has no repeated root then it doesn't happen in general

Anyway  *carat*, the original poster, is right: for $n=1$ it is false. It even makes no sense talking of multiple root for $n=1$

Suppose the root are $3$ then we have

$P(x)=(x - a) (x - b) (x - c)$

Use the condition that $P(a+1)=1;\;P(b+1)=1;\;P(c+1)=1$

$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \left( {a + 1 - a} \right)\left( {a + 1 - b} \right)\left( {a + 1 - c} \right) = 1 \hfill \\
  \left( {b + 1 - a} \right)\left( {b + 1 - b} \right)\left( {b + 1 - c} \right) = 1 \hfill \\
  \left( {c + 1 - a} \right)\left( {c + 1 - b} \right)\left( {c + 1 - c} \right) = 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
which simplifies to
$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \left( {a - b + 1} \right)\left( {a - c + 1} \right) = 1 \hfill \\
  \left( {b - a + 1} \right)\left( {b - c + 1} \right) = 1 \hfill \\
  \left( {c - a + 1} \right)\left( {c - b + 1} \right) = 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

which is verified when $a=b=c$

Therefore $x=a$ is a triple root. $P(x)=(x-a)^3$

In a similar way it can be proved for any degree

Comment: Ok you got a system of three non linear equations with three unknowns. In principle you do not know whether there are one, two, or infinitely many solutions. You have to prove that, *for each possible solution*, at least two unknowns are equal.. Now?